# how to get more than one number inside of matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, numbers

Ok. I have a simple question although I'm still fairly new to Matlab (taught myself). So I was wanting a `1x6` matrix to look like this below:

```
0

0

1

0

321, 12      <--- needs to be in one box in 1x6 matrices

4,30,17,19   <--- needs to be in one box in 1x6 matrices
```

Is there a possible way to do this or am I going to just have to write them all in separate boxes thus making it a `1x10` matrix?

My code:

```
event_marker = 0;
event_count  = 0;
block_number = 1;

date = [321,12] % (its corresponding variables = 321 and 12)

time = [4,30,17,19] % (its corresponding variable = 4 and 30 and 17 and 19)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "be in one box"?

Comment: when you click on a variable in the workspace it usually shows you a matrix numbers. if your variable has more than one number it creates it in the next cell.  in my case id like the varibles with 2 numbers i.e. date and time to have those two numbers in that one cell instead of making its own cell for each number

Comment: Look up cell arrays: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html

Comment: @Dan did you understand my question though?

Comment: @Stokes yes fairly sure I did. Also two answers below suggest the same thing.

Comment: @Dan. Thanks dude! it was easier than I thought I just didn't know anything about cell arrays.

Answer (score 3):

So if I understand you correctly, you want an array that contains 6 elements, of which 1 element equals `1`, another element is the array `[312,12]` and the last element is the array `[4,30,17,19]`.

I'll suggest two things to accomplish this: matrices, and cell-arrays.

### Cell arrays

In Matlab, a `cell` array is a container for arbitrary types of data. You define it using curly-braces (as opposed to block braces for matrices). So, for example,

```
C = {'test', rand(4), {@cos,@sin}}
```

is something that contains a string (`C{1}`), a normal matrix (`C{2}`), and another cell which contains function handles (`C{3}`).

For your case, you can do this:

```
C = {0,0,1,0, [321,12], [4,30,17,19]};
```

or of course,

```
C = {0, event_marker, event_count, block_number, date, time};
```

### Matrices

Depending on where you use it, a normal matrix might suffice as well:

```
M = [0  0  0  0 
     event_marker  0  0  0 
     event_count  0  0  0
     block_number  0  0  0 
     321 12  0  0
     4 30 17 19];
```

Note that you'll need some padding (meaning, you'll have to add those zeros in the top-right somehow). There's tonnes of ways to do that, but I'll "leave that as an exercise" :)

Again, it all depends on the context which one will be easier.

Comment: THANK YOU @RODY you might have just locked in my software eng intern position to full time thanks dude. My boss is going nuts right now hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) rather than matrices for your task.

```
data = cell(6,1); % allocate cell
data{1} = event_marker; % note the curly braces here!
...
data{6} = date;   % all elements of date fits into a single cell.
```

Comment: OMG Thanks @Shai that def is what i was looking for. i dont know how to give you points on here. can you show me?

Comment: @Stokes: Just click on the "up" arrow above the big number to the left of someone's answer. This will "upvote" the answer, giving 10 points to the answerer, and affecting the display order of all answers to your question. In addition, you can "accept" the answer you consider the best one, which will give 15 points to the answerer, and place that answer on top (regardless of what the number of up/downvotes for all other answers are). Also have a read through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` and `time` variables are actually represent date (numbers of days, months, years) and time (hours, mins, sec), they can be packed into one or two numbers.

Look into [DATENUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) function. If you have a vector, for example, `[2013, 4, 10]`, representing April 10th of 2013 you can convert it into a serial date:

```
daten = datenum([2013, 4, 10]);
```

It's ok if you have number of days in a year, but not months. `datenum([2013, 0, 300])` will also work.

The time can be packed together with date or separately:

```
timen = datenum([0, 0, 0, 4, 30, 17.19]);
```

or

```
datetimen = datenum([2013, 4, 10, 4, 30, 17.19]);
```

Once you have this serial date you can just keep it in one vector with other numbers.

You can convert this number back into either date vector or date string with [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) and [DATESTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) function.